# vmware player host vpn no internet

Tags: vpn, vmware-player

I am running a vw machine on the host computer that has 2 active connections. One is ethernet broadband and second is VPN via broadband. And there's no internet in vm machine, only vpn is accessible. But I need only internet there, how to do that? VM is behind NAT